# A question on combinatorial algorithm

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, randomized-algorithms

Given n sets $S_1,...,S_n$ such that $S_i \subset \{1,...,n\}$ is there a poly(n) algorithm to find $1 \leq i_1 < i_2 <.... < i_k \leq n$ such that $|\bigcup_{j=1}^k S_{i_j} | = k$ where $1 \leq k < n$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears that the problem is NP-Complete via a reduction for Exact-3-Cover (with some modifications). It may be worth trying.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri, I can't see how to use Exact-3-Cover to show that the problem is NP-Hard. If possible, can you expand on your comment?

Comment: @NealYoung I didn't mean to allow $k=0$ edge case. I modified the question.

Comment: Put $k=|\bigcup_iS_i|$, and for each $x\in\bigcup_iS_i$, pick one $S_i$ that contains it. If this results in less than $k$ sets, add any of the remaining ones to make it right.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, there was a typo k < n in the question, which I edited. Your algorithm will fail for k = n.

Comment: RIshabh see [the posting guidelines](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  They suggest including background info such as where the problem arises, what you know about it, what you've tried...

Comment: I think I prefer the following formulation: Given a bipartite graph $E\subseteq[n]\times[n]$, find $\varnothing\ne X\subsetneq[n]$ such that $|X|=|E(X)|$ (or: $|X|\ge|E(X)|$) if it exists.

Comment: Yes, I meant neighbours. For the $|X|=|N(X)|$ version, $N(X)$ is nonempty because $X$ is, but you are right that in the $|X|\ge|N(X)|$ version, I should demand $N(X)\ne\varnothing$ rather than $X\ne\varnothing$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*EDIT*: Added second proof, using Hall's theorem.]

---

**Theorem 1.** *There is a poly-time algorithm for the problem.*

We give a direct proof, then another proof using [Hall's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem).

Both proofs use the following utility lemma,
which recasts the problem into a more convenient form.

Fix a problem instance $(S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_n)$.
The problem is to decide
whether the instance is *feasible*,
meaning that there exists $C\subseteq [n]$
such that $n-1 \ge |C| = |\bigcup_{i\in C} S_i| \ge 1$.

If there is a set $S_i$ of size 1, the instance is feasible
(take $C=\{i\}$), so assume otherwise.
Note that in the definition above
WLOG we can restrict to collections $C$
containing at least one index $a$ with $|S_a| \ge 2$,
and *not* containing at least one other index $b\in[n]$.

Given $(a,b)\in [n]\times [n]$ with $|S_a| \ge 2$ and $a\ne b$,
define subproblem $\mathcal S(a, b)$ as follows.
Let $S'_1, S'_2, \ldots, S'_{n-2}$ be obtained
from $S_1, \ldots, S_n$ by
removing the two sets $S_a$ and $S_b$,
then replacing each remaining set $S$
by $(S \setminus S_a) \cup \{n+1, n+2, \ldots, n+|S_a|-2\}$.
(This removes all elements in $S_a$ from the problem,
and adds $|S_a|-2$ new elements to each remaining set.
Intuitively, this
forces $S_a$ to be chosen,
forces $S_b$ not to be chosen,
and artificially increases the size of any (non-empty)
union of the sets by $|S_a|-2$.)
The subproblem is to determine whether
$\mathcal S(a, b)$ is feasible,
meaning that there exists $C'\subseteq [n-2]$
such that
$$\textstyle|C'| \ge 1 + \big|\bigcup_{i\in C'} S'_i\big|.$$

**Lemma 1.** *The original instance is feasible iff
at least one such subproblem $\mathcal S(a,b)$ is feasible.*

(We leave as an exercise to verify
that the original instance is feasible iff,
for at least one such subproblem $\mathcal S(a, b)$,
there exists $C'\subseteq [n-2]$ such that
$|C'|$ *equals* $1 + \big|\bigcup_{i\in C'}S'_i \big|.$
Then, per Emil's comment,
relaxing the equality to a ``$\ge$''
is okay because in the case that $|C'|$ is too large,
one can choose one set from $C'$ containing
each element of $\bigcup_{i\in C'} S'_i$,
then choose additional, redundant sets from $C'$ as necessary
to achieve the correct size.)

By the lemma, it suffices to show that
each of the $O(n^2)$ subproblems is solvable in poly time.
The first proof below does this using linear programming
and randomized rounding.
The second proof does it using Hall's theorem.

---

###### First proof sketch (using randomized rounding)

Consider the following linear-program relaxation of
$\mathcal S(a, b) = (S'_1, S'_2, \ldots, S'_{n'})$,
with no objective function:

$$\textsf{LP}(a, b) = {} \begin{cases}\begin{align}
\textstyle {\sum_{i=1}^{n'} x_i}
& {} \ge 1 + \textstyle \big(\sum_{j=1}^{n'} y_j\big) \\
x_i &{} \le y_j && (i\in [n'], j \in S'_i) \\
0 \le x_i &{} \le 1 && (i\in [n']) \\
0 \le y_j &{} \le 1 && (j\in [n'])
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

---

Here is the algorithm for solving $\mathcal S(a, b)$:

1. solve LP$(a, b)$ using any poly-time LP solver
2. if the LP admits a feasible solution: return 'yes'
3. else: return 'no'

---

*Remark.* If a solution, rather than just a yes/no decision,
is required, one can adapt the rest of the proof to show that
from any feasible solution, a solution to the original problem
instance can be computed in poly time.  Or, more informatively,
that the basic feasible solutions (BFS) to the LP are 0/1,
so that by using a standard LP solver
that returns a BFS, a solution
to the original problem can be found in poly time.

---

To finish we prove correctness of the algorithm.

**Claim 1.** *If there is a solution
$(S'_{i_1}, \ldots, S'_{i_k})$ to $\mathcal S(a, b)$,
then there is a corresponding feasible 0/1-solution $(x,y)$
to LP$(a, b)$.*

(Indeed, let $C'= \{i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k\}$.
Take $x_i = 1$ if $i\in C'$
and $y_j = 1$
if $j\in \bigcup_{i\in C'} S'_i$.)

From Claim 1, it follows that if the algorithm returns 'no',
then $\mathcal S(a, b)$ has no solution, so the algorithm
is correct in this case.
To finish, we prove the following claim,
which implies that the algorithm is also correct
in the case that it returns 'yes'.

---

**Claim 2.** *If LP$(a, b)$ is feasible,
then $\mathcal S(a, b)$ has a solution.*

To prove it, consider the following randomized rounding scheme:

1. let $(x, y)$ be a feasible solution to LP$(a, b)$
2. choose a value $\lambda\in (0,1]$ uniformly at random
3. let r.v. $C = \{i : \lambda \le x_i\}$
4. let r.v. $U = \{j : \lambda \le y_j\}$

---

Note that
$i \in C \wedge j \in S'_i
\implies \lambda \le x_i \wedge x_i \le y_j
\implies \lambda \le y_j
\implies j \in U$.

It follows that $\bigcup_{i\in C} S'_i \subseteq U$.

On the other hand, the expected sizes of $C$ and $U$
are related (via the LP constraints) as follows
$$\textstyle E[|C|] = \sum_{i=1}^{n'} x_i
\ge 1 + \big(\sum_{j=1}^{n'} y_j\big)
= 1 + E[|U|].$$

Since $E[|C| - |U|] \ge 1$,
there is an outcome of the experiment in which
$$\textstyle |C| \ge 1 + |U| \ge 1 + |\bigcup_{i\in C} S_i|,$$ as desired.
$~~~\Box$

---

###### Second proof sketch (using Hall's theorem)

Fix a subproblem instance
$\mathcal S(a, b)=(S'_1, S'_2, \ldots, S'_{n'})$.
Recall that the goal is to determine whether
there exists $C\subseteq [n']$
such that
$$\textstyle|C| \ge 1 + \big|\bigcup_{i\in C} S'_i\big|.$$

The instance is *infeasible* if and only if,
for all $C\subseteq [n']$,
$$\textstyle|C| \le |\bigcup_{i\in C} S'_i|.$$
By [Hall's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem),
this condition holds for all $C$ if and only
$\mathcal S(a, b)$ has a *transversal*,
meaning a matching that
assigns each set $S'_i$ a distinct element $j\in S'_i$
(so that no element is assigned to more than one set).
Thus, infeasibility can be determined
by solving the bipartite-matching problem
in the bipartite graph representing the set system $\mathcal S(a, b)$.

Bipartite matching is solvable in polynomial time,
so we are done.
(If there is no such matching,
existing poly-time algorithms
prove it by returning a dual solution,
in the form of a set $C$ such that
$\textstyle|C| > |\bigcup_{i\in C} S'_i|.$
This then gives a solution to $\mathcal S(a, b)$.)
$~~~~\Box$

Comment: Nice. I thought of using LP, but didn’t have enough determination to actually figure it out. Note that the last part can be alternatively proved using the argument I gave above in the comments: once $|C|\ge|\bigcup_{i\in C}S_i|$, pick $i_x\in C$ such that $x\in S_{i_x}$ for each $x\in U':=\bigcup_{i\in C}$, and let $\{i_x:x\in U'\}\subseteq C'\subseteq C$ be such that $|C'|=|U'|$.

Comment: Thanks @EmilJeřábek, I incorporated your argument (now in the proof of Lemma 1).

Comment: My intuition was incorrect, that is why I hedged a bit. @NealYoung glad that you didn't get swayed and found the algorithm.